# How can I schedule a Task to execute at a specific time using celery?

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks, celery

I've looked into `PeriodicTask`, but the examples only cover making it recur. I'm looking for something more like `cron`'s ability to say "execute this task every Monday at 1 a.m."

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The recently released version 1.0.3 supports this now, thanks to Patrick Altman!

Example:

```
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import periodic_task

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=7, minute=30, day_of_week="mon"))
def every_monday_morning():
    print("This runs every Monday morning at 7:30a.m.")
```

See the changelog for more information:

http://celeryproject.org/docs/changelog.html

Comment: The import paths have been changed to `from celery.task import periodic_task` and `from celery.schedules import crontab`

Answer (score 38):

Use

```
YourTask.apply_async(args=[some, args, here], eta=when)
```

And at the end of your task, reschedule it to the next time it should run.

Comment: don't forget eta is a python's datetime,

Comment: If I make it a `PeriodicTask`, I only need to schedule it the first time, right?

Answer (score 6):

I have just submitted a patch to add a ScheduledTask to accomplish a small bit of time based scheduling versus period based:

https://github.com/celery/celery/commit/e8835f1052bb45a73f9404005c666f2d2b9a9228

Answer (score 2):

While @asksol's answer still holds, the api has been updated. For celery 4.1.0, I have to import `crontab` and `periodic_task` as follows:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task
```