# Celery - schedule periodic tasks starting at a specific time

Tags: python, celery, scheduled-tasks

What is the best way to schedule a periodic task starting at specific datetime?

(I'm not using cron for this considering I've the need to schedule about a hundred remote rsyncs, 
where I compute the remote vs local offset and would need to rsync each path the **second** the logs are generated in each host.)

By my understanding the celery.task.schedules crontab class only allows specifying hour, minute, day of week.
The most useful tip I've found so far was [this answer by nosklo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990531/how-can-i-schedule-a-task-to-execute-at-a-specific-time-using-celery/1990599#1990599).

Is this the best solution?
Am I using the wrong tool for the job?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Celery seems like a good solution for your scheduling problem: Celery's PeriodicTasks have run time resolution in seconds.

You're using an appropriate tool here, but the crontab entry is not what you want.  You want to use python's datetime.timedelta object; the crontab scheduler in celery.schedules has only minute resolution, but using timedelta's to configure the PeriodicTask interval provides strictly more functionality, in this case, per second resolution.

e.g. from the Celery docs

```
>>> from celery.task import tasks, PeriodicTask
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> class EveryThirtySecondsTask(PeriodicTask):
...     run_every = timedelta(seconds=30)
...
...     def run(self, **kwargs):
...         logger = self.get_logger(**kwargs)
...         logger.info("Execute every 30 seconds")
```

http://ask.github.com/celery/reference/celery.task.base.html#celery.task.base.PeriodicTask

```
class datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0)
```

The only challenge here is that you have to describe the frequency with which you want this task to run rather than at what clock time you want it to run; however, I would suggest you check out the Advanced Python Scheduler http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/

It looks like Advanced Python Scheduler could easily be used to launch normal (i.e. non Periodic) Celery tasks at any schedule of your choosing using it's own scheduling functionality.

Comment: Thanks bakennedy. I *am* using APScheduler, was just checking Celery to see if I could improve my current system. I had already read the PeriodicTask page, but though it allows specifying the task frequency, it doesn't specify *when* will it start.

Comment: My current setup: a daemonized APScheduler which reads which tasks will it start (start_time, frequency, process_to_call) from a .cfg file. Problem is, I have to SIGKILL the daemon each time there's any change in the task (the offset between my local server and the remote log generation is now different; i need a different frequency; the process arguments changed) seeing that APScheduler ShelveJobStore only allows updates from the main loop (and doesn't reload a file ShelveJobStore for instance), which defeats the daemon purpose.

Comment: Ah, I had misunderstood APScheduler and thought that it was merely a timing library for scheduled to delayed execution of a task from within some program, not a scheduling daemon and job management system.  There's more overlap than I thought with celery; however, celery still is definitely a superior task management tool, especially if your jobs are large enough to need to be distributed amongst separate worker nodes.

Comment: PeriodicTask seems to be deprecated.

Comment: @alper Do you have more info on that?

Answer (score -1):

I've recently worked on a task that involved Celery, and I had to use it for asynchronous operation as well as scheduled tasks. Suffice to say I resorted back to the old crontab for the scheduled task, although it calls a python script that spawns a separate asynchronous task. This way I have less to maintain for the crontab (to make the Celery scheduler run there needs some further setup), but I am making full use of Celery's asynchronous capabilities.

Comment: If you are running celery anyways, why not run it with beat and use the crontab scheduling?