# What is the best way to make an event happen at a set rate? Using time.sleep() is very unreliabe. Can things be locked to a timer of sorts?

Tags: python

I'd like a function to be performed at a set rate, say, 6 times a second. What it is the best way to go about this with Python?

I tried a simple time.sleep() thing at the end of my loop, but that, of course, acts nothing like a reliable clock. Any change in CPU usage, and suddenly the "timer" has drifted quite far from where it started.

Comment: Does it matter if the events are equally spread over the second? i.e. could you perform all 6 events in the first 0.1s and then wait for 0.9s?

Comment: @Ben Yeah, I'm trying to create an FPS kind of clock, So I need those subsecond events to fire at a fairly accurate rate. What I get now, is a lot of "drift" in the timer.

Comment: Unless you use a real-time OS and *all* code run is very carefully written, you'll never get really accurate results. You can reduce the error quite a bit though, probably enough to not be measurable easily, is that okay?

Comment: @Ben As long as it doesn't drift more than a second out of sync, I think I'd be fairly pleased

Comment: what do you want to happen if the function takes more than 1/6 of a second? Do you have an event loop in your program? Have you tried [`pygame.time.set_timer`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer)-like solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Try [`celery`](http://celeryproject.org/). Example:

```
from celery.task import tasks, PeriodicTask
from datetime import timedelta

class Every100MillisecondsTask(PeriodicTask):
    run_every = timedelta(milliseconds=100)

    def run(self, **kwargs):
        logger = self.get_logger(**kwargs)
        logger.info("Execute 10 times per second")
```

Untested, but should work. You can change the values to get the resolution you need. You can even pass in microseconds for the timedelta. Actually adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848512/celery-schedule-periodic-tasks-starting-at-a-specific-time).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.  It won't drift because it is anchored to a fixed start time.

```
import time

def repeat(func, interval):
    start = time.time()
    tick = interval / 50.0
    count = 0
    while True:
        if time.time() >= start + interval * count:
            func()
            count += 1
        time.sleep(tick)
```

If you want to run function `foo` six times each second, do:

```
def foo(): 
    print '.',

repeat(foo, 1.0 / 6)
```

**edit:**  I like mccrustin's answer to use celery, but if you need to roll your own this answer should work.