# How to parametrize crontabschedule on celery periodic task?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

Is there a way of parametrize the django celery crontab schedule value for periodic tasks that starts after defined datetime?

Lets say we have users on django that saves tasks with an specific datetime that starts a day of weekday and must be executed weekly.

tasks.py

```
from celery.task import periodic_task
from celery.schedules import crontab

@periodic_task(ignore_result=True, run_every=crontab(minute=0,hour=0,day_of_week='saturday'))  # every minute
def just_print():
    print "Print from celery task"
```

models.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
    start_time = models.TimeField()        
    weekday= models.CharField()
    start = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.start_time, self.start)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       just_print.run_every=crontab(minute=self.start_time.minute,hour=self.start_time.hour,day_of_week=self.weekday) # << Something like this 
just_print.apply_async(eta=(start))
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990531/how-can-i-schedule-a-task-to-execute-at-a-specific-time-using-celery/1990599#1990599) answer but i want  hours, minutes and weekdays defined by users for executions as periodic tasks